# Not able to bind image with image url in Android DataBinding with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-jetpack

I am facing issues in setting image url to image view using data binding in Kotlin.
I have used BindingAdapter but still image is not populated with image url. Please find below the source and resource files used and help me in resolving this issue.

My Data class is as below:

```
 data class ItemInfo(val img:String,val fname:String,val lname:String){

   companion object {
    @BindingAdapter("img")
    @JvmStatic
    fun loadImage(imageView: ImageView, url: String) {
    if (url != "") {
        // Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).load(url).resize(200, 200).into(imageView).
        Picasso.get().load(url).into(imageView)
    }

}


}
 }
```

My Layout is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

<data>
    <variable name="item"
              type="com.example.jetpackmvvmdemos.DataBindingAdapter.models.ItemInfo">
    </variable>
</data>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
     android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
     android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="10dp">

   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:img="@{item.img}"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" 
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" 
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="@{item.fname}"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" 
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" 
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="@{item.lname}"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" 
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" 
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

ViewModel:

```
class EmpViewModel:ViewModel() {
    var empInfoList:MutableList<ItemInfo>
    init {
        empInfoList = mutableListOf<ItemInfo>()
        empInfoList.add(ItemInfo("https://via.placeholder.com/50x50.png?text=1","ABC","DEF"))
        empInfoList.add(ItemInfo("https://via.placeholder.com/50x50.png?text=2","GHI","JKL"))
        empInfoList.add(ItemInfo("https://via.placeholder.com/50x50.png?text=3","MNO","PQR"))
        empInfoList.add(ItemInfo("https://via.placeholder.com/50x50.png?text=4","STU","VWX"))

    }

}
```

Adapter:

```
class ListInfoAdapter(var context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListInfoAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    private var list: List<ItemInfo> = emptyList<ItemInfo>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        val binding: ListItemBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        return ListInfoAdapter.ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
       // Log.d("ADapter", "Info:::" + list.get(position).body)
        holder.bind(list.get(position))
    }

    fun setAdapterList(list: List<ItemInfo>) {
        this.list = list
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = list.size

    class ViewHolder(val binding: ListItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(data: Any) {
            binding.setVariable(BR.item, data) // BR - generated class; BR.item - 'item' is variable name declared in layout
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
class DataBindingListFragment: Fragment() {

    var fragmentView: View? = null
    private var listAdapter: ListInfoAdapter? = null
    private var listLayoutBinding: com.example.jetpackmvvmdemos.databinding.EmpInfoListFragmentLayoutBinding? = null
   // lateinit var empViewModel: EmpViewModel
    val empViewModel: EmpViewModel by lazy { ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(EmpViewModel::class.java) }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        listLayoutBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.emp_info_list_fragment_layout, container, false)
        fragmentView = listLayoutBinding?.root
        initAdapter()
        setAdapter()
        fetchEmpInfo()
        return fragmentView
    }




    fun fetchEmpInfo() {
        listAdapter?.setAdapterList(empViewModel.empInfoList)

    }


    fun setAdapter(){
        fragmentView?.emprecyclerView?.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(activity, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
            adapter = listAdapter
        }
    }

    private fun initAdapter() {
        listAdapter = ListInfoAdapter(this@DataBindingListFragment.requireActivity())
    }
}
```

Build.Gradle (App level)

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jetpackmvvmdemos"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    ext.compiler_version = '3.3.1'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$compiler_version"
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    def lifecycle_version = "2.1.0"
    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
}
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

Comment: I am uncertain why you have that `BindingAdapter` defined on a `companion object` of a seemingly-unrelated class. Since this affecting `ImageView`, you can define it as an extension function on `ImageView` itself. See [this `BindingAdapter`](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/blob/v0.6/Bookmarker/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/bookmarker/BindingAdapters.kt) and [this layout that uses it](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/blob/v0.6/Bookmarker/src/main/res/layout/row.xml).

Comment: I tried by using extension fncn, still not able to view image

Comment: Perhaps there is an issue with the URL or with Picasso's ability to use it. Check Logcat for messages.

Answer (score 0):

In DataBinding Adapter :

// BindingAdapter.kt  file

// set Picasso image

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
  fun loadImage(view: ImageView, imageUrl: String) {
  Picasso.get()
 .load(imageUrl)            
 .into(view)
```

// set drawable image

```
fun setImageDrawable(view: ImageView, drawable: Drawable) {
view.setImageDrawable(drawable)
 }

}
```

// in xml

```
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgHexaLeft"
        android:layout_width="53dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
         app:imageUrl="@{historyData.backgroundImg}"
     />
```

Same you can set the drawable.